# Handling Dynamic Calendar State Changes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'm currently working on a ReactJS project to create a dynamic calendar where users can interact with dates, submit tasks, and view task details. I've encountered some challenges and would appreciate suggestions.

Project Goals:

Generate a dynamic calendar displaying the current date.
Allow users to change the year or month to view other dates.
Enable task submission for specific dates.
Display task details upon clicking on a date.
Approach and Challenges:

Initially, I generate the calendar by mapping an array of dates for the whole month using the JavaScript Date object, like this: new Date(fullYear, month+1, 0).
To simplify complexities, I opted for a straightforward rendering approach using the map() function on an array generated by Array(wholeDayFunction).
Each day is rendered as a  element, and to uniquely identify each date, I added a data-id attribute with a value derived from the concatenation of the year, month, and day. This ensures that each date has a unique identifier.
Clicking on a date (onClick event) sets its unique identifier as the id in the state, facilitating task submission and interaction.
Additionally, I implemented a separate component for adding tasks. This component takes two main parameters: id and task.
The id parameter corresponds to the unique identifier of the selected date stored in the state, ensuring tasks are associated with the correct date.
Upon task submission, the system compares the task's id with the data-id attribute of the  representing the date fields. If they match, certain actions, such as changing the background color of the date fields, are executed.

However,I believe a more efficient solution would involve generating objects for each date with properties like id, year, month, day, and task, stored in state. This approach would allow easier manipulation of individual dates and tasks.
However, implementing this solution poses challenges, especially regarding the generation and management of objects for future dates. For example, unnecessary objects may be generated, leading to performance issues or conflicts.

I'd appreciate suggestions on the best approach for generating and managing dynamic calendars with task submission functionality in ReactJS.
If my current approach is not optimal, I'm open to alternative solutions or corrections to steer me in the right direction.
Any insights or guidance to improve my understanding and implementation would be immensely helpful.

Some part of my current solution :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import AddTask from "./assets/AddTask";
import Calender from "./assets/Calender";

function App() {
  const [taskText, setTaskText] = useState("");
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]);
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  function handleAddTask() {
    const taskObject = { id: selectedDate, task: taskText };
    if (task.some((item) => item.id === taskObject.id)) return;
    setTask((prevTasks) => [...prevTasks, taskObject]);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Calender setSelectedDate={setSelectedDate} task={task} />

      <AddTask
        onAddTask={handleAddTask}
        selectedDate={selectedDate}
        taskText={taskText}
        setTaskText={setTaskText}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

    export default function Calender({ setSelectedDate, task }) {
      const [year, setYear] = useState(new Date().getFullYear());
      const [month, setMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
      const dateFileds = useRef([]);
      function getDaysInMonth() {
        return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
      }
    
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "grid",
            gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(7, 1fr)",
            width: "80%",
            margin: "5rem auto",
            placeContent: "center",
            placeItems: "center",
            gap: "16px",
            cursor: "pointer",
          }}
        >
          {[...Array(getDaysInMonth())].map((_, index) => (
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                textAlign: "center",
                width: "100%",
                height: "5rem",
                border: "1px solid black",
                background: task.find(
                  (field) =>
                    field.id === Number(dateFileds.current[index].dataset.id)
                )
                  ? "red"
                  : "transparent",
              }}
              key={index}
              ref={(e) => (dateFileds.current[index] = e)}
              data-id={new Date(year, month, index + 1)
                .toLocaleDateString()
                .split("/")
                .join("")}
              onClick={(e) => {
                setSelectedDate(Number(e.target.dataset.id));
              }}
            >
              {new Date(year, month, index + 1).toLocaleDateString()}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    
    export default function AddTask({ onAddTask, taskText, setTaskText }) {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <textarea
            value={taskText}
            name=""
            id=""
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            onChange={(e) => setTaskText(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <button onClick={onAddTask}>Add</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
        enter code here
    
    >
```